# java logback - how to insert hash of last log at end of last file and start of next file?

Tags: java, logging, hash, logback, rollingfileappender

I need to write certain audit data to file (possibly from multiple threads). The historical integrity of the audit data within these files is important.

When the log file rolls over (likely that this will be time based rollover, but configurable within the system), I want to generate a digital hash of the entire log file contents and append the hash value as the last line in the log file, then close the file, create the next log file and insert the exact same hash as the first line of the new log file.

Thus it will be possible to look at historic log files and prove that auditable data has not been trimmed or edited.

Is there a mechanism within Logback I can use to achieve this?
Or is there a sensible way to extend Logback's functionality?
Or is this beyond the scope of what Logback is there to do and I should be inserting hashes into file tail/top using a separate mechanism?

Thanks for any suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is something beyond the scope of Logback.

You may want to look at [Logback Audit](http://audit.qos.ch/). From the site:

> Logback-Audit is designed for logging events which have long-term
>   business significance. Logback-audit is open-source software based on
>   logback-core.